# Iterator in my implementation of std::list does not work

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, linked-list, iterator

I'm trying to write a template of list like std::list one.
This is my code in List.h:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T, class Node>
class iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, Node *, Node &> {
    Node *underlying;

public:
    explicit iterator(Node *n) : underlying(n) { };

    iterator() : underlying(nullptr) { };

    iterator &operator++() { //preinc
    assert(underlying != nullptr && "Out-of-bounds iterator increment!");
    underlying = underlying->next;
    return *this;
    }

    iterator operator++(int) { //postinc
    assert(underlying != nullptr && "Out-of-bounds iterator increment!");
    iterator temp(*this);
    ++(*this);
    return temp;
    }

    iterator &operator--() { //predec
    assert(underlying != nullptr && "Out-of-bounds iterator decrement!");
    underlying = underlying->previous;
    return *this;
    }

    iterator operator--(int) { //postdec
    assert(underlying != nullptr && "Out-of-bounds iterator decrement!");
    iterator temp(*this);
    --(*this);
    return temp;
    }

    bool operator==(const iterator &rhs) {
    return underlying == rhs.underlying;

    }

    bool operator!=(const iterator &rhs) {
    return underlying != rhs.underlying;

    }

    T &operator*() {
    return underlying->data;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class List {

    class Node {
    public:
    T data;
    Node *previous;
    Node *next; //is that T needed?
    Node(T &d) : data(d) { };
    };

private:

    Node *head; //first element
    Node *tail;

    void create() { head = tail = NULL; }

    void create(const List &rhs) {
    iterator this_iter = head;
    iterator rhs_iter = rhs.head;
    while (rhs_iter != NULL) {
        this_iter->data = (rhs_iter++)->data;
        ++this_iter;
    }
    };

public:
    typedef T *iterator;
    typedef const T *const_iterator;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef T value_type;

    List() { create(); };

    List &operator=(const List &rhs) {
    if (&rhs != this) {
        create(rhs);
    }
    return *this;
    };

    List(const List &rhs) { create(rhs); };

    ~List() { while(head) remove(head); };

    T *begin() { return head; };

    T *end() { return tail; };

    T front() { return head->data; };

    T back() { return tail->data; };

    bool empty() { return head == NULL; }

    size_type size() {
    size_t i = 0;
    Node *node = head;
    while (node) {
        node = node->next;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
    };

    T &operator[](size_type i) {
    if (i < size() && i >= 0) {
        Node *temp = head;
        while (i > 0) {
            temp = temp->next;
            i--;
        }
        return temp->data;
    }
    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    };

//    const T &operator[](size_type i) const; //how to implement and do not duplicate code?

    Node *push_back(value_type data) {
    Node *n = new Node(data);
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = tail = n;
    } else {
        n->previous = tail;
        tail->next = n;
        tail = n;
    }
    return n;
    };

    Node *push_front(value_type data) {
    Node *n = new Node(data);
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = tail = n;
    } else {
        n->next = head;
        head->previous = n;
        head = n;
    }
    return n;
    };

    void pop_front() {
    remove(head);
    };

    void pop_back() {
    remove(tail);
    };

    void remove(Node *n){
    if(n == NULL) return;
    if(n == head){
        head = n->next;
        head->previous =NULL;
    }
    else if(n == tail){
        tail = n->previous;
        tail->next = NULL;
    }
    else{
        n->previous->next = n->next;
        n->next->previous = n->previous;
    }
    delete n;
    }


};
```

And this is main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"
int main(){
    List<int> l;
    l.push_back(1);
    l.push_back(2);
    l.push_back(3);
    l.pop_back();
    l.pop_front();
    l.push_back(4);
    l.push_back(5);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < l.size(); i++)
        std::cout << l[i] << "\n";
    std::cout<<"Front "<<l.front();
    std::cout<<"Back "<<l.back();
}
```

Actually push_back/front , pop_back/front and []operator work fine. But I get "Process finished with exit code 139" 
error when I try use front() or back(). And I know that this iterator of list template does not work but I do know how to combine it up. Could anyone hint or help?

EDIT:
Ok, I have fixed the problem with removing and front(), tail() methods. But still the iterator thing doesnt work.
For example this code:

```
for(List<int>::iterator it = l.begin(); it!=l.end(); it++){
        std::cout << it << "\n";
    }
```

Gives me erros:

```
error: cannot convert ‘List<int>::Node*’ to ‘List<int>::iterator {aka int*}’ in initialization
     for(List<int>::iterator it = l.begin(); it!=l.end(); it++){
                                          ^
error: comparison between distinct pointer types ‘List<int>::iterator {aka int*}’ and ‘List<int>::Node*’ lacks a cast [-fpermissive]
     for(List<int>::iterator it = l.begin(); it!=l.end(); it++){
                                                       ^
```

I know that te problem is with wraping the node with iterator template and that I have got "typename T *iterator".

Comment: your `Node(T &d)` does not set neither `next` nor `previous`...probably not a big issue

Comment: Test this code! Create empty List - check if it is empty - call its functions verify if everything works correctly. Create List with one element - call List functions - verify everything works. Do the same for two elements List. etc etc...

Comment: And then, if you still can't figure out your problem, you'll need to construct a minimal program to reproduce it before anyone else is likely to be able to help

Comment: I have tested it. I added my main.cpp file

Answer (score 3):

Your `begin` and `end` methods return `Node*`, not your iterator type. And you made the iterator constructor that accepts `Node*` as an argument `explicit`; you *told* the compiler that implicit conversion from `List<int>::Node*` to `List<int>::iterator` is disallowed.

You must do one of:

1. Remove `explicit` from `explicit iterator(Node *n) : underlying(n) { };` (though this risks implicit conversions in scenarios you don't want)
2. Change `begin` and `end` to return `iterator(head)` and `iterator(tail)` (performing explicit conversion to `iterator`) rather than `head` and `tail` (and change the return type of `begin` and `end` to `iterator`, which you should really do regardless)

You have some other issues too:

1. You should not have done `typedef T* iterator` in `List`; that hid the definition of your `iterator` class, so `List` never used it. Fixing that (and adding the necessary templating to your uses of `iterator`) makes it compile
2. The inheritance definition of `iterator` should be `template<typename T, class Node> class iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T>` not `template<typename T, class Node> class iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, Node *, Node &>`; the latter is declaring the value from dereferencing should be `Node *` (when you want it to be `T`, the value in each `Node`)
3. `end` should return `iterator<T, Node>(nullptr)` not `iterator(tail)`; otherwise, you stop before printing the value of `tail`, when you want to print `tail` before you terminate the loop.

Once all that is done, you should compile and get the results you expect. The code still has problems, e.g.

1. It's not `const` correct and offers no `const` versions of various accessors, which can prevent optimizations; you may end up recomputing `size` on every loop if the compiler can't figure out that the loop is *actually* non-mutating
2. The copy constructor/assignment utility function `create` doesn't work (you'd want to iterate over `rhs` and `push_back` repeatedly, you can't use an `iterator` to push on new values
3. The lack of `const` accessors means that utility function can't be made to work; it would need a `const` iterator type to iterate `rhs` with a guarantee that it would not violate the `const List&` requirement, but you only defined mutating iterator functions

But that it performance optimizations and correctness in code you're not exercising; you can fix that once you're satisfied with the new code.

I've [your code](http://cpp.sh/2ln7) (though the fix to copy construction/assignment is an egregious hack using `const_cast` to brute force around the lack of `const` safe iteration); I also added a couple tests to show that copy construction and assignment work. [Take a look](http://cpp.sh/6oxeg).

Comment: @Mateusz: You forgot to change the return type of `begin` and `end` to match. They need to return `iterator`, not `Node*`. Fixing that compiles and runs.

Comment: hmm, still the same error. http://cpp.sh/2ln7 I assume you meant *begin() and *end() methods

Comment: @Mateusz: You left the `*` in. They shouldn't return `iterator *`, they should return `iterator`. They used to return `Node*` because returning a copy of a `Node` was nonsensical, but for an `iterator` (a thin wrapper around a `Node*`), you want to return by value, not by reference/pointer. That said, I just noticed you used a `typedef` that replaced `iterator` for the definition of `List`, so you weren't using your `iterator` class anyway. There were a number of other issues; I've updated the answer to address more of them.

Comment: @Mateusz: And now that cpp.sh seems to work again, I've provided a [link to modified code](http://cpp.sh/6oxeg) that fixes all these problems (though it's using an `const_cast` hack to work around the lack of a `const` friendly `begin`/`end`; I didn't want to implement totally new code).

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. Unftunatelly when I copy this code into my IDE i have a lot of errors like: *error: ‘List<T>::iterator’ is not a template
     iterator<T, Node> begin() { return iterator<T, Node>(head); };*

Comment: @Mateusz: This is probably because you're using iterators with explicit declaration outside the class (not using for-each loops or `auto` to declare/init the iterator). For ease of use, you may want to use a `using` statement to make a template free definition of `List<T>::iterator` (e.g. `using iterator=::iterator<T, Node>;`, so the `<T, Node>` isn't needed when referring to it either inside or outside the class). This [final version of the code provides that `using` statement and adjusts `begin`/`end` to match, as well as testing it by using explicit loop](http://cpp.sh/9fyzl).

Answer (score 1):

The problem (a problem?) is in `remove()`: you don't check if `head` is `NULL` (`head` case), if `tail` is `NULL` (`tail` case) and if `n->previous` and `n->next` are null (generic case)

I suggest this `remove()`

```
void remove(Node *n){
   if(n == NULL) return;
   if(n == head){
      head = n->next;
      if ( head )
         head->previous =NULL;
   }
   else if(n == tail){
      tail = n->previous;
      if ( tail )
         tail->next = NULL;
   }
   else{
      if ( n->previous )
         n->previous->next = n->next;
      if ( n->next )
         n->next->previous = n->previous;
   }
   delete n;
}
```